# std::string::replace standard implementation?

Tags: c++, string

In every language that I can think of, except C++, the function Replace essentially replaces all pieces of a string, whereas C++'s string class does not support simple operations like the following:

```
string s = "Hello World";
s = s.Replace("Hello", "Goodbye");
echo s; // Prints "Goodbye World"
```

This seems the most common use of any type of string replace function, but there doesn't seem to be a standard replace function in C++. Am I missing something here?

EDIT: I'm aware that there's not a built-in replace function like this in the standard library -- I'm wondering if there is a more or less standard implementation made from standard algorithms or something of that sort.

Comment: I always had the same complaint.  I don't think there's any solution in STL except to use find in conjunction with replace.

Comment: Similar question with more solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418231/replace-part-of-a-string-with-another-string

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not missing anything, its not in the standard library.
You can either write that yourself using `find()`, `replace()` etc. or use an implementation like [`replace_all()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/replace_all.html) from Boosts [string algorithm library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/string_algo.html).

Answer (score 0):

this is not exactly the same but there is a replace method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main( void )
{
        string s = "Hello World";

        s.replace(0, 5, "Goodbye");

        cout << s << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

you can easily write your replacement using string::find, string::replace and a little loop