# Convert a string with '\b' escape character (backspace) to a normal string

Tags: c++, special-characters, unicode-escapes

My string:

```
std::string With_esc = "asd\b";
```

I want to convert it to a simple string "as" (apply the backspace character and forget it).
Is there any way to do this in C++? It should look like this:

```
std::string With_esc = "asd\b";
std::string Without_esc = With_esc; //Here I should convert it
std::ofstream FWith_esc ("with");
std::ofstream FWithout_esc ("without");
FWithout_esc << Without_esc;
FWith_esc << With_esc;
```

Bash:

```
~ cat -e with
  asd^H
~ cat -e without
  as
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to convert it, so both files look exactly the same.

Comment: best chance is to do a search'n'replace yourself, it shouldn't be too hard

Comment: I'd go with a regex "(.\\b)" to replace with ""

Comment: @MarcoA. Well replacing the '\b' character with '' will not consume it. The string variable will still contain "asd" instead of "as".

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Would you want `"aa\b\b"` to become `"a\b"`, or do you want it to become `""`?

Comment: @user3125731 if the backspace character is the only one you need to deal with you can take care of the previous digit as well. If not then it might be a problem (or a lot of work). There might be a better solution I don't see right now (except passing stuff in a bash shell)

Comment: And what should happen if the `'\b'` is the first character of the string?

Comment: @hvd good question...I assumed just one escape otherwise he may need looping (or a better regex, I'm really not such good with them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're lucky enough to use C++11 (otherwise adapt this code to your favorite regex engine):

```
string With_esc = R"asd\b";
string Without_esc = regex_replace(With_esc, regex(".\\b"), "");
```

As pointed out in comments this approach has following limitations:

- It'll replace only one "back" so if you have `"12\b\b"` you'll get `"1\b"`. To handle this you need to loop until input and output (for `regex_replace()`) are different (or *maybe* a better regex, I'm not such good with them).
- It won't handle `\b` as beginning of the string like in `"\b123"`. To handle this you need a simple string replacement (using technique suggested by [Giobunny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25037937/1207195)) to remove `\b` after a `regex_replace`().
- Note here I'm using verbatim strings (it's ok for an example if your text comes from a file but if you're working with string literals you need to update regex accordingly).

**UPDATE**
As noted by [Eric Finn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407071/eric-finn) this expression will also match multiple backspaces then `"a\b\b\b"` will become `"\b\b"` and then `"\"`, that's obviously wrong. As he suggested a better regex should include check for `"[^\b]\b"` too.

Comment: Simplest way to go IMHO. +1

Comment: Why do you need the parentheses in the regular expression?

Comment: Fortunately I'm using C++11. What is reg() function? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: You can use C++11 [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) for regex expressions for less hassle with escape chars, e.g. `std::regex{R"(.\b)"}` (parentheses needed for raw string literal).

Comment: Strange, because with updated gcc (4.9.1) and std=c++11 flag I get ‘reg’ was not declared in this scope error.

Comment: @user3125731 just include "regex" header (and std namespace).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti that's exactly what I did but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @user3125731 ROFL sorry, typo: it's not "reg" but "regex"!

Comment: Shouldn't this be something like `[^\b]\b`? I would think that this regex would match `a\b\b\b` in `aaa\b\b\b`.

Comment: @EricFinn yes but (maybe) OP wants to transform "aaa\b\b\b" in "" (emtpy string: 3 "a" deleted by 3 backspaces).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Exactly. However, if you match `a\b\b\b`, you will have a backspace deleting an `a` and a backspace deleting a backspace.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, if you don't want to use a regex:

```
std::string convertBackspaces(std:string str)
{
    std::string::iterator iter = str.begin();
    std::string::iterator end = str.end();
    while (iter != end)
    {
        iter = std::find(iter, end, '\b');
        if (iter == end) break;
        if (iter == str.begin())
            iter = str.erase(iter);
        else
            iter = str.erase(iter-1, iter+1);
        end = str.end();
    }
    return str;
}
```

```
std::string Without_esc = convertBackspaces(With_esc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the substring `"\b"` with an empty string.
It's not the fastest/safest method but it will work,
you can follow.

[Replace substring with another substring C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643512/replace-substring-with-another-substring-c)

Comment: He wants it to also remove the previous character; \b is backspace