# Removing capitals and lengthening contractions in a string

Tags: c++, input

I'm trying to replace any capitals as well as lengthening any contractions used in a string. I'm trying to find the fastest and most efficient approach.

Here is my attempt, which is not working:

*Note: `ur` is the 'unrefined input'*

```
//Removing Capitals
std::transform(ur.begin(), ur.end(), ur.begin(), ::tolower);
//Removing Contractions
std::replace( ur.begin(), ur.end(), "it's", "it is");
```

Here is what's included in the program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
```

Comment: Please, only one question each. Also, it may be interesting, but for the title it is completely irrelevant that you are trying to write a chatbot. However, what is relevent is e.g. the type of `ur` and the issues you have with your code. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, your question as it stands is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Your post contains two different questions, both of which are duplicates, and you are not saying *what* "is not working".

**Removing capitals**

The way you are writing it is correct if you are using ASCII characters *only*.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lower-case/24063783#24063783) for more details about supporting locales and other encodings.

**Replacing contractions**

This is very hard if you want it to be efficient.
If you just want to replace each contraction one by one, you shouldn't use [`replace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/replace/) (it will only replace characters, not substrings). Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643512/replace-substring-with-another-substring-c/4643526#4643526).