# C++ How to replace number for letter

Tags: c++, string, replace, letters-and-numbers

well I would like to know how to change number by letter, I would like to replace the number `1` with `:x:`
Here's my code:

```
string stng;

printf("Enter with number:");
cin >> stng;

replace(stng.begin(), stng.end(), '1', 'x');

cout << stng << endl;
```

as you can see I'm using this to replace: `replace(stng.begin(), stng.end(), '1', 'x');`
but as soon as I can only change `1` for `x`, I want to replace for `:x:`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643512/… http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418231/… I seems for C++ it is not so trivial task :(.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a character in string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896600/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-character-in-string)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this

```
string stng;

printf("Enter with number:");
cin >> stng;

replace(stng.begin(), stng.end(), '1', ":x:");

cout << stng << endl;
```

Comment: but its no possible give me a erro if i use 'x' no error ! :c

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use.  It will take a `std::string` and replace all occurrences of the `from` input string to the `to` input string.

```
std::string replaceAll(const std::string & s, const std::string & from, const std::string & to)
{
    string res(s);
    string::size_type n1 = from.size();
    string::size_type n2 = to.size();
    string::size_type i = 0;
    string::size_type j = 0;
    while ((i = res.find(from, j)) != string::npos)
    {
        res.replace(i, n1, to);
        j = i + n2;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I think there's a bug if the `from` string is empty.

Comment: no, that's right, you are calling the from inside the while :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do that better with the `replace` member function of `std::string`.

```
auto pos = stng.find("1"); // search for 1 in the string
if (pos!=stng.npos)  // check if 1 is found
{
   stng.replace(pos, 1, ":x:");   // replace ":x:" starting from 'pos' to 'pos+1'
}
```

And your job is done !!!

Comment: Hum that's nice, is working very well! I had never seen "auto" in C ++ will study more about it! thx :D

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by delim `'1'` into tokens using this [`split`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/2210478) function.

Then merge the string by `":x:"` using the following function

```
std::string merge(const std::vector<std::string>& v, const std::string& glue)
{    
    std::string result;
    if(v.empty()) { return result; }
    result += v[0];
    for(size_t i = 1; i != v.size() ; i++)
    {
        result += glue;
        result += v[i];
    }
    return result;
}

std::string replace(const std::string& src, char delim, const std::string& glue)
{
    return merge(split(src, delim), glue); 
}
```

Live is [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/uNBI4gq8aqMNz5TB)