# inserting the \ character into a string

Tags: c++

I am tryin to insert a \ charcter into a string so I would get

C:\\Users\\dave\\Desktop\\XY.txt
instead of 
C:\Users\georg\Desktop\XY.txt

here is code but for some reason it does not work

```
string q="C:\Users\georg\Desktop\XY.txt";
char x='\\';


for (int i = 0; i < q.length(); ++i) {
if (q[i] == '\\')
 q.insert(i,4,x);
 }
```

Comment: If you want really a string that contains `C:\\Users\\dave\\Desktop\\XY.txt`, you need to use `"C:\\\\Users\\\\dave\\\\Desktop\\\\XY.txt"`.

Comment: Even if the string is correct, the `for` will have infinite insertions.

Answer (score 5):

Just write

```
string q="C:\\Users\\georg\\Desktop\\XY.txt";
```

Or use a raw string literal

```
string q=R"(C:\Users\georg\Desktop\XY.txt)";
```

Comment: the thing is I do not declare the string this just a simple example the users clicks on a file and I get the string q="C:\Users\georg\Desktop\XY.txt" after that I would like to add the extra \ everywhere so I can open in my code  the file that is referenced using  .open(q)

Comment: @georges There is no need to add the extra '\' character. The string already contains a valid file name. '\\' is an escape character that is converted to character '\' at the compile time while you are speaking about the run-time.

Comment: This does not work       :string q=R"(C:\Users\georg\Desktop\XY.txt)";
                                       myfile1.open(q);    It only works with two \ ...

Comment: We both got fooled by the first mistake Vlad. Seems there is a bigger mistake, you also should fix your answer.

Comment: I just realized it was not working because I am using mcvs 2010 thank you however

Comment: @georges Maybe instead of  the string itself you should use q.c_str() to open the file.

Comment: @georges I think you should close this question and ask a new question that contains the relevant code. As for the original question then there is no any need to insert redundant '\' characters. You should elaborate what does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You should use \ within quotes to add a single . So your first line is the problem. It should be

```
string q="C:\\Users\\georg\\Desktop\\XY.txt";
```

Then the rest will work.

**EDIT**

after additional explanation, I found problems with the follow up code. It should be fixed to the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < q.length(); ++i) {
    if (q[i] == '\\') {
        q.insert(i,1,x);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Let me explain, first of all, you need only 1 additional \ so second parameter of insert should be 1. After inserting, you need to skip inserted \, hence i++;

Comment: wouldn't this result in 5 backslashes in the string including the one that is already there?

Comment: As you might know \ is escape character, so anything after \ might have an additional meaning \g is simply g and \\ is \ .

Comment: he thing is I do not declare the string this just a simple example the users clicks on a file and I get the string q="C:\Users\georg\Desktop\XY.txt" after that I would like to add the extra \ everywhere so I can open in my code the file that is referenced using .open(q)

Comment: sure i get that, but after applying your suggested edit, `q.insert(i,4,x)` will insert 4 backslashes just before the existing backslash making the count 5 right?

Comment: I now noticed that, you are right and fixed my answer.

Comment: @CemKalyoncu  I downloaded a cpp compiler that supports R string however now I need to convert from string to R string to use your method since the user will provide a regular string in this format C:\Users\georg\Desktop\XY.txt. and I can't find anything online about that

Comment: You don't need to perform anything on the user string. \\ is a requirement for your input within quotes. If you read your string from a file, a \ is a \ you don't need to perform any additional operations on it. If you give a more complete answer I might understand the issue better.

Answer (score 1):

### Objective

Add an extra backslash to each one found in the string (for use in another program)

### Current issues

1. Example string is not escaped properly (easiest is to use a raw string)
2. The `for` loop inserts 4 backslashes at a time and so will never reach the end.

### Solution with C++11

This will add a backslash to each one that is already there:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string q = R"(C:\Users\georg\Desktop\XY.txt)";

    char x='\\';


    for (int i = 0; i < q.length(); ++i) {
        if (q[i] == '\\') {
            q.insert(++i,1,x);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Solution without raw strings

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    //std::string q = R"(C:\Users\georg\Desktop\XY.txt)";
    std::string q = "C:\\Users\\georg\\Desktop\\XY.txt";

    char x='\\';


    for (unsigned i = 0; i < q.length(); ++i) {
        if (q[i] == '\\') {
            q.insert(++i,1,x);
        }
    }

    std::cout << q;

    return 0;
}
```

### [Result](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2712fced837d2583)

```
C:\\Users\\georg\\Desktop\\XY.txt
```

Comment: it gives me undeclared identifier R even though I have the same copy pasted code

Comment: @georges Raw string literal is a C++11 feature, may be your compiler doesn't support C++11.

Comment: It works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2712fced837d2583), but I'll add a version that doesn't need the raw string.

Comment: oh yeah It's because I am using mcvs 2010 as a compiler thank you

Comment: @flatmouse  I downloaded a cpp compiler that supports R string however now I need to convert from string to R string to use your method since the user will provide a regular string in this format C:\Users\georg\Desktop\XY.txt. and I can't find anything online about that

Comment: @georges When the user provides the string you don't need to use `R` or raw strings. You only need it if you want the convenience in source code when typing the constant. If you accept user input into a string all the characters will be there as provided. If your program doesn't work as expected then post a new question with the code and examples of what does not work (sample input and output).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first line either needs to be a [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) or have `\\` in it:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string q  = R"(C:\Users\georg\Desktop\XY.txt)"; // Raw (C++11 and higher)
    string q2 = "C:\\Users\\georg\\Desktop\\XY.txt"; // Escaped

    cout << q << "\n"   // Outputs: C:\Users\georg\Desktop\XY.txt
         << q2 << "\n"; // Outpits: C:\Users\georg\Desktop\XY.txt
}
```

As written, it is trying to use `\U`, `\g`, etc. as special characters.

---

*Update*: To actually do what you are asking, you'd want to do something like:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// From http://stackoverflow.com/a/15372760/201787
void replaceAll( string &s, const string &search, const string &replace ) {
    for( size_t pos = 0; ; pos += replace.length() ) {
        // Locate the substring to replace
        pos = s.find( search, pos );
        if( pos == string::npos ) break;
        // Replace by erasing and inserting
        s.erase( pos, search.length() );
        s.insert( pos, replace );
    }
}

int main()
{
    string q = R"(C:\Users\georg\Desktop\XY.txt)"; // Raw (C++11 and higher)
    string q2 = "C:\\Users\\georg\\Desktop\\XY.txt"; // Escaped
    string q3;
    std::cin >> q3; // Does not handle whitespace

    replaceAll( q, "\\", "\\\\" );
    replaceAll( q2, "\\", "\\\\" );
    replaceAll( q3, "\\", "\\\\" );

    cout << q << "\n"
         << q2 << "\n"
         << q3 << "\n";
}
```

Which prints the following if the user enters `C:\Users\georg\Desktop\XY.txt`
:

```
C:\\Users\\georg\\Desktop\\XY.txt 
C:\\Users\\georg\\Desktop\\XY.txt
C:\\Users\\georg\\Desktop\\XY.txt
```

Comment: That will give him the string `C:\Users\georg\Desktop\XY.txt`. But the question asked how to get `C:\\Users\\dave\\Desktop\\XY.txt`.

Comment: wouldn't this result in 5 backslashes in the string including the one that is already there?

Comment: Does that raw string really work? Shouldn't it be `std::string q = R"(C:\Users\georg\Desktop\XY.txt)"; // Raw`?

Comment: he thing is I do not declare the string this just a simple example the users clicks on a file and I get the string q="C:\Users\georg\Desktop\XY.txt" after that I would like to add the extra \ everywhere so I can open in my code the file that is referenced using .open(q)

Comment: do you think it's possible to do it with the same string as q i.e one \  only it won t be a raw string?

Comment: @georges: Yes. See `q3` which I've added to the update.