# Replace a character/sequence of characters in a C++ std::string with another sequence of characters

Tags: c++, string, c++11, replace, stdstring

I want to replace all occurrences of `&` in my `std::string` with `&amp;`. Here, is the code snippet 
[codelink](http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/tX7ki6)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string st = "hello guys how are you & so good & that &";
    std::replace(st.begin(), st.end(), "&", "&amp;");
    std::cout << "str is" << st;
    return 1;
}
```

It shows error that std::replace can't replace string, but it only works with characters. 
**I know i can still have a logic to get my work done, but is there any clean C++ way of doing this ? Is there any inbuilt function ?**

Comment: [`std::string::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace). You should be familiar with cppreference by now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [regex replace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41294178/1460794) could make this easier:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string st = "hello guys how are you & so good & that &";
    st = std::regex_replace(st, std::regex("\\&"), "&amp;");
    std::cout << "str is" << st;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped :) Upvoted & accepted as answer :)