# replace 2 characters with 3 three in a string

Tags: c++, replace

I'm trying to replace "\n" with  "\n" but I'm not allowed to do it with this function:

```
std::replace(encryptedKey.begin(), encryptedKey.end(), "\n", "\\n");
```

encryptedKey is a long string.

I think I get the error because I'm trying to replace with more characters, is there any other solutions for doing this in a string?

Edit 1:

> Error : Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error (active)  E0304   no instance of function template "std::replace" matches the argument list   encryption  c:\Users\heltbork\source\repos\encryption\encryption\encryption.cpp 274

Comment: What you are trying to achieve with that replacement?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: You should recheck how replace [works](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace).  Your going to need the `find` function to help you with this.

Comment: check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643512/replace-substring-with-another-substring-c

Comment: Error (active) E0304 no instance of function template "std::replace" matches the argument list encryption

Comment: @NathanOliver Okay :)