# std::replace - Compiler deduces a char type from const char* literal converted explicitly to string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, stl

**I want to replace my buffer string from a value of `"eof"` to `"\0"` using `std::replace`.**

```
std::string buffer = "eof";
std::replace(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), std::string("eof"), std::string("\0"));
```

##### Compiler error :

```
no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘char’ and ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’)
```

Comment: [`std::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) takes *single element* to replace from and to.

Comment: Perhaps you should use [`std::string::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) instead?

Comment: Note that `"\0"` is treated as `""`, is that what you really want? Do you want to replace `"eof"` with a blank string? If so, then just use `""` (or even just `string{}`). But, if you want to replace `"eof"` with an actual `'\0'` nul character, then you need to use `std::string("\0", 1)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that internally `std::replace` checks `==` on `*first` and `old_value` where `first` is the first argument passed(iterator here) and `old_value` is the third argument passed shown in the below [possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace):

```
template<class ForwardIt, class T>
void replace(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last,
             const T& old_value, const T& new_value)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
//----------vvvvvv    vvvvvvvvv--------->compares *first with old_value
        if (*first == old_value) {
            *first = new_value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now `*first` is `char` and `old_value`(and `new_value`) is `std::string` in our example and since there is no `operator==` for checking if a `char` and a `std::string` are equal and also as there is no implicit conversion between the two, we get the mentioned error.

One way to solve this is to use `std::string::replace`. More alternatives can be found at : [Replace substring with another substring C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643512/replace-substring-with-another-substring-c)

Comment: Why is the Forward Iterator (first) a char though?

Comment: @apetrai Because we passed the first argument `buffer.begin()` which is of `std::string::iterator`. This means `first` is of type `std::string::iterator`. And thus when you dereference `first` like `*first` we get `char` as a `std::string` consists of `char` elements.  In other words, dereferencing the iterator gives us the element inside the container. Just to give you an analogy suppose we had a `vector<int>` then we would have gotten `*first` as `int`.

Comment: Thank you very much. You're very good at explaining answers.

Comment: @apetrai In other words, dereferencing the iterator(like `*first`) gives us the element inside the container which in case of `std::string` is nothing but `char`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::string::replace`, if you intention is to replace all occurences of `eof` substring with `\0` then I suggest using standard method as in:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace

```
std::size_t replace_all(std::string& inout, std::string_view what, std::string_view with)
{
    std::size_t count{};
    for (std::string::size_type pos{};
         inout.npos != (pos = inout.find(what.data(), pos, what.length()));
         pos += with.length(), ++count) {
        inout.replace(pos, what.length(), with.data(), with.length());
    }
    return count;
}
```

Your code should look as follows:

```
std::string buffer = "eof";
replace_all(buffer, "eof", "\0");
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4110765b0f265aae