# C++: How does one replace all instances of a character in a string with another character?

Tags: c++

I found this method on the internet:

```
//the call to the method: 
cout << convert_binary_to_FANN_array("1001");

//the method in question: 
string convert_binary_to_FANN_array(string binary_string)
{
string result = binary_string;

replace(result.begin(), result.end(), "a", "b ");
replace(result.begin(), result.end(), "d", "c ");
return result;
}
```

But this gives

```
main.cpp:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘replace(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, const char [2], const char [3])’
```

Comment: Have you done #include <algorithm> ? (You also need to qualify with `std::` or use `using`, but I'm guessing you've already done that since otherwise you'd have a bunch of other compilation errors.)

Comment: Sorry, ignore above comment. Correct answer coming in 15 seconds :-).

Comment: Once you've done it test it out by replacing all occurrences of the sequence "ass" with "butt"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need characters, not strings, as the third and fourth arguments to `replace`. Of course that won't do if you really want to replace `'a'` with `"b "`.

So, e.g.,

```
string convert_binary_to_FANN_array(string binary_string)
{
    string result = binary_string;

    replace(result.begin(), result.end(), 'a', 'b');
    replace(result.begin(), result.end(), 'd', 'c');
    return result;
}
```

will turn `a`s into `b` and `d`s into `c`s (though why you'd be doing that to a string containing only 0s and 1s, I can't imagine). It won't, however, insert any extra spaces.

If you do need the extra spaces, see (1) the reference provided by Timo Geusch and (2) this: [Replace part of a string with another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418231/c-replace-part-of-a-string-with-another-string).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation for `std::string`'s family of replace functions:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/

You'll see that there is none that allows you to specify a string and a replacement string, they mostly work with offsets/iterators and the replacement.

The boost libraries have a whole slew of replacement algorithms that might be much better suited:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id2728305

Answer (score 0):

Another approach if you want to localize the replace's is using a functor...

Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct replaceChar
{
   void operator()(char& c) { if(c == 'a') c = 'b'; }
};

std::string str = "Ababba";

std::for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), replaceChar() );
```