# Indenting multiline output by specified number of characters

Tags: c++

I want to be able to output multiple lines and have them all indented by a specified number of characters. So, if we have

```
int n = 3;
```

this would be the number of characters to indent, and then we had the string,

```
string s = "This is a string.\nThis is a string.\nThis is a string\n";
```

and I were to then output the string,

```
cout << s;
```

how could I make it so every line that is outputted is indented by `n`?

Comment: I'm courious to see the answer...basically the goas is mess with buffers and substiture \n with \n + n spaces...

Comment: @buttifulbuttefly I was hoping there was a more straightforward solution, but alright, I will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crude workaround would be to find all instances of `\n` in the string to be printed and add a string containing blank space characters of specified length after every occurrence of `"\n"`.

if `ss` is the string to be printed, and `empty` is a string containing blank space characters, then replace all instances of `"\n"` in `ss` by `"\n" + empty`

Refer to [How to find and replace string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878775/how-to-find-and-replace-string) for code on doing this.

Depending on your application, you could convert this to a function, and try overloading `cout` to call it while printing any strings (not sure if it will work).

Comment: So this is exactly what I was thinking and looking for, but with regards to the code, would `s.replace(s.find("\n"), 2, "\n" + spaces)` replace all instances of `\n` or just the first one? I didn't really get that clarification in the link you shared.

Comment: I think the top answer would only replace a single occurrence. You could look at the Boost library in the second answer if you want. Else, refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343190/how-do-i-replace-all-instances-of-of-a-string-with-another-string

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a `string` variable that will store the spaces, then add spaces to it by looping.

```
int n = 3;
string indents;

for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
    indents += " ";
```

Combining everything in one string,

```
string s = "This is a string.\n" + indents + "This is a string.\n" + indents + "This is a string\n" + indents;
```

`cout << s;`

**EDIT:**
Since you mentioned that the occurrences or positions of `\n` are unknown,

You can use [string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) to find the first occurrence of `\n`, then add `n` spaces after it using [string::insert](http://www.programmingincpp.com/string-insert-function.html) then loop until all occurrences of `\n` are found and spaces are added after it.

```
int n = 3;
string s = "This is a string.\nThis is a string.\nThis is a string\n";

// first occurrence
size_t pos = s.find("\n");

while (pos != string::npos) {

    // insert n spaces after \n
    s.insert(pos + 1, n, ' ');

    // find the next \n
    pos = s.find("\n", pos + 1);
}
cout << s;
```

Output

```
This is a string.
   This is a string.
   This is a string.
```

Comment: So I have gotten far enough in that I have used a similar idea to the spaces with `string spaces(n, ' ');` but the problem is that I won't know where the newlines are in s or if there will be any at all, so I am guessing that I will need to search through and find the index of all the \n characters and append the spaces.

Comment: If that's the case, you can take a look at this link:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/replace_all.html