# C++ replace all substrings in string

Tags: c++, string, replace

I apologize if this already has been answered but I didn't manage to find a solution on exactly this. I want to find all occurrences of a specific substring in a string and then replace those substrings with something else, for example:

```
int main(){
    // Variabeldeklaration
    string str = "elephant elephant duck duck elephant";

    if (/* string contains "elephant" */){
        // replace_all "elephant" , "gorilla";
    }

    // Now str = "gorilla gorilla duck duck gorilla";

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I know it's possible to replace all char found in a string but I want to be able to replace more than one char. How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace part of a string with another string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418231/replace-part-of-a-string-with-another-string). Or [Replace substring with another substring C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643512/replace-substring-with-another-substring-c). Or [How do I replace all instances of a string with another string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343190/how-do-i-replace-all-instances-of-a-string-with-another-string).

Comment: I found that answer earlier, however this does only replace the first substring it finds and not all of them.

Comment: *That*  - which one? The third link is actually what you need. Besides, replacing `if` with `while` is not a rocket science.

Comment: Sorry I clicked the link on top of the page, thanks

Comment: I cannot reclose as I already cast a close vote. I do not think reclosing is that necessary though.

Comment: Was there another of the questions that Wiktor linked that you'd rather have this one closed as a duplicate of? I can change the duplicate if that would make the answer easier to find.