# Replacing instances of a given std::string with another std::string in C++

Tags: c++, string, std

I have been looking online without success for something that does the following. I have some ugly string returned as part of a Betfair SOAP response that uses a number of different char delimiters to identify certain parts of the information. What makes it awkward is that they are not always just one character length. Specifically, I need to split a string at `':'` characters, but only after I have first replaced **all** instances of `"\\:"` with my personal flag `"-COLON-"` (which must then be replaced again AFTER the first split).

Basically I need all portions of a string like this

```
 "6(2.5%,11\:08)~true~5.0~1162835723938~"
```

to become

```
 "6(2.5%,11-COLON-08)~true~5.0~1162835723938~
```

In perl it is (from memory)

```
 $mystring =~ s/\\:/-COLON-/g;
```

I have been looking for some time at the functions of `std::string`, specifically `std::find` and `std::replace` and I know that I can code up how to do what I need using these basic functions, but I was wondering if there was a function in the standard library (or elsewhere) that already does this??

Comment: Have you looked at the C++11 RegEx facilities?
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/regex/
It includes match-replace operations
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/regex/match_replace/

Comment: Im not too up on C++11 as the compiler I am currently writing this on does not support C++11. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Replace part of a string with another string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418231/c-replace-part-of-a-string-with-another-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`boost::replace_all(input_string, "\\:", "-COLON-");`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.replace_hpp)

Comment: Sometimes I wish the standard had stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have C++11 something like this ought to do the trick:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
std::string str("6(2.5%,11\\:08)~true~5.0~1162835723938~");
std::regex rx("\\:"); 
std::string fmt("-COLON-");
std::regex_replace(str, rx, fmt);

return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** There is an optional fourth parameter for the type of match as well which can be anything found in `std::regex_constants` namespace I do believe. For example replacing only the first occurrence of the regular expression match with the supplied format.