# C++ - Replace spaces with %20

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am looking for a way to prepare a string for use as a URL.

The basics of the code is you type in what you are looking for and it opens a browser with what you typed in. I am learning C++, so this is a learning program. And please be as specific as possible for I am new to C++.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
cin >> s_input;
transform(s_input.begin(), s_input.end(), s_input.begin(), tolower);
s_input = "start http://website.com/" + s_input + "/0/7/0";
system(s_input.c_str());
```

But I am trying to replace all the spaces the user enter with a '%20'. I have found one method this way but it only works with one letter at a time, and I am needing to do it with a full string and not an array of chars. Here is the method I have tried:

```
cin >> s_input;
transform(s_input.begin(), s_input.end(), s_input.begin(), tolower);
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::replace;
replace(s_input.begin(), s_input.end(), ' ', '%20');
s_input = "start http://website.com/" + s_input + "/0/7/0";
system(s_input.c_str());
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What you're actually trying to do is escape all special characters in a string.  Space is not the only character illegal in URLs.

Comment: For basic "find and replace" on strings, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3418231/501250).  But you should really consider using a third-party library to properly URI-encode the string instead.

Comment: @wug You are correct about that. But this is simply a learning program and I can only take it one step at a time. I will be the only one using this..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio 2010 or later you should be able to use [regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) to search/replace:

```
std::regex space("[[:space:]]");
s_input = std::regex_replace(s_input, space, "%20");
```

**Edit:** How to use the six-argument version of [`std::regex_replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace):

```
std::regex space("[[:space:]]");
std::string s_output;
std::regex_replace(s_output.begin(), s_input.begin(), s_input.end(), space, "%20");
```

The string `s_output` now contains the changed string.

You might have to change the replacement string to `std::string("%20")`.

As you see I have only five arguments, that's because the sixth should have a default value.

Comment: EDIT: Found you must also "#include <regex>". Found this by visiting the link

Comment: OK, i tried this method and it gives me this error:  "No instance of overloaded function std::regex_replace matches the argument list"  and it also gives me "expects 6 arguments - 3 provided"

Comment: @alexander7567 Added example showing how to use the six-argument version of the function.

Answer (score 1):

`std::replace` is only able to replace single elements (chars in this case) with single elements.  You are trying to replace a single element with three.  You will need a special function to do that.  Boost has one, called [`replace_all`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/replace_all.html), you can use it like this:

```
boost::replace_all(s_input, " ", "%20");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you google: C++ UrlEncode, you will find many hits.  Here's one:

http://www.zedwood.com/article/111/cpp-urlencode-function