# String replacement in C++ on string of arbitrary length

Tags: c++, macos, stdstring, ostringstream

I have a string I get from `ostringstream`. I'm currently trying to replace some characters in this string (`content.replace(content.begin(), content.end(), "\n", "");`) but sometimes I get an exception:

```
malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=4294955008) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
std::bad_alloc
```

I suspect that this happens because the string is too big. What's the best practice for these situations? Declare the string on the heap?

**Update**

My full method:

```
xml_node HTMLDocument::content() const {
  xml_node html = this->doc.first_child();
  xml_node body = html.child("body");
  xml_node section = body.child("section");
  std::ostringstream oss;
  if (section.type() != xml_node_type::node_null) {
    section.print(oss);
  } else {
    body.print(oss);
  }
  string content;
  content = oss.str();
  content.replace(content.begin(), content.end(), "<section />", "<section></section>");
  content.replace(content.begin(), content.end(), "\t", "");
  xml_node node;
  return node;
}
```

Comment: If you're looking for help with this specific problem, I think you'll need to provide a [minimal, verifiable and complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There's a decent chance that the error has nothing to do with this particular piece of code. Did you try running this with valgrind?

Comment: I can't run valgrind on OSX.

Comment: Perhaps you want the boost::string methods, particularly [boost::algorithm::replace_all](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/replace_all.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no [`std::string::replace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) member function's overload that accepts a pair of iterators, a `const char*` to be searched for and `const char*` to be used as replacement, and this is where your problem comes from:

```
content.replace(content.begin(), content.end(), "\n", "");
```

matches the following overload:

```
template <class InputIterator>
string& replace(iterator i1, iterator i2,
                InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

that is, `"\n"` and `""` is treated as the range `<first; last)`, which, depending on what addresses do they have, crashes your program or not.

You have to either use [`std::regex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex) or implement your own logic that iterates through `std::string` and replaces any encountered pattern with a replacement string.

Comment: he could be using the [replace method from algorithm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/replace/) that does have 2 iterators, an old and new char parameter.

Comment: @gbjbaanb: no, there is no *empty character* `''`, and OP also tries to replace entire string as well

Comment: ah yes - the title says replace characters but the code says remove them. So sloppy :)

Comment: For the record, I've used the solution in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418231/replace-part-of-a-string-with-another-string

Comment: There's no way `""` can match `size_t`; `size_t` is an integral type, and `""` is an array, which can convert to a pointer, but not to an integral type.

Answer (score 1):

The lines:

```
content.replace(content.begin(), content.end(), "<section />", "<section></section>");
content.replace(content.begin(), content.end(), "\t", "");
```

result in undefined behavior.  They match the function:

```
template<class InputIterator>
std::string& std::string::replace(
    const_iterator i1, const_iterator i2,
    InputIterator j1, InputIterator j2);
```

with `InputIterator` resolving to `char const*`.  The problem is
that the distance between the two iterators, and whether the
second can be reached from the first, is undefined, since they
point to totally unrelated bits of memory.

From your code, I don't think you understand what
`std::string::replace` does.  It replaces the range `[i1,i2)` in
the string with the text defined by the range `[j1,j2)`.  It
does *not* do any search and comparison; it is for use *after*
you have found the range which needs replacing.  Calling:

```
content.replace(content.begin(), content.end(), "<section />", "<section></section>");
```

has exactly the same effect as:

```
content = std::string( "<section />", "<section></section>");
```

, which is certainly *not* what you want.

In C++11, there's a `regex_replace` function which may be of
some use, although if you're really doing this on very large
strings, it may not be the most performant (the added
flexibility of regular expressions comes at a price); I'd
probably use something like:

```
std::string
searchAndReplace(
    std::string const& original,
    std::string const& from,
    std::string const& to)
{
    std::string results;
    std::string::const_iterator current = original.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = original.end();
    std::string::const_iterator next = std::search( current, end, from.begin(), from.end() );
    while ( next != end ) {
        results.append( current, next );
        results.append( to );
        current = next + from.size();
        next = std::search( current, end, from.begin(), from.end() );
    }
    results.append( current, next );
    return results;
}
```

For very large strings, some heuristic for guessing the size,
and then doing a `reserve` on `results` is probably a good idea
as well.

Finally, since your second line just removes `'\t'`, you'd be
better off using `std::remove`:

```
content.erase( std::remove( content.begin(), content.end(), '\t' ), content.end() );
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK stl strings are always allocated on the heap if they go over a certain (small) size, eg [32 chars in Visual Studio](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/06367898-d42a-4c0d-a83f-1042c44b1b4e/strings-allocate-in-stack-or-heap)

What you can do if you get allocation exceptions:

- Use a custom allocator
- Use a "[rope](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ropeimpl.html)" class.

Bad alloc might not mean you're run out of memory, more likely that you're run out of contiguous memory. A rope class might be better suited to you as it allocated strings in pieces internally.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the correct (and reasonably efficient) ways to remove characters from a string if you want to make a copy and leave the original intact:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

std::string delete_char(std::string src, char to_remove)
{
    // note: src is a copy so we can mutate it

    // move all offending characters to the end and get the iterator to last good char + 1
    auto begin_junk = std::remove_if(src.begin(),
                                     src.end(),
                                     [&to_remove](const char c) { return c == to_remove; });
    // chop off all the characters we wanted to remove
    src.erase(begin_junk,
              src.end());

    // move the string back to the caller's result
    return std::move(src);
}
```

called like this:

```
std::string src("a\nb\bc");
auto dest = delete_char(src, '\n');
assert(dest == "abc");
```

If you'd prefer to modify the string in place then simply:

```
src.erase(std::remove_if(src.begin(), src.end(), [](char c) { return c == '\n'; }), src.end());
```

Comment: Why `std::remove_if`, and not simply `std::remove`?

Comment: why not indeed? There are many correct ways to skin a c++ cat.

Comment: But the simplest is usually best.  Introducing a lambda here when there is a function which already does exactly what is wanted is unnecessary complication.

Comment: I think that's a fair comment. Nevertheless, the hope is that the OP learns the general principle of remove/erase in stl and then goes on to lead a happier life. :-)

Comment: Yes.  That's a bit why I pointed out the algorithm using `std::search`.  It's a bit more complicated than using `std::regex_replace`, but it introduces a useful pattern.