# Print a string like "First\nSecond" on two lines

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

**Aim:** to read a string in the form `First\nSecond` from a file and to print it as

```
 First
 Second
```

**Problem:** if the string is defined in the code, as in `line = "First\nSecond";`, then it is printed on two lines; if instead I read it from a file then is printed as

```
First\nSecond
```

Short program illustrating the problem:

```
#include "stdafx.h"     // I'm using Visual Studio 2008
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void main() {
  std::ifstream ParameterFile( "parameters.par" ) ;
  std::string line ;
  getline (ParameterFile, line) ;
  std::cout << line << std::endl ;
  line = "First\nSecond";
  std::cout << line << std::endl ;

  return;
}
```

The parameters.par file contains only the line

```
First\nSecond
```

The Win32 console output is

```
C:\blabla>SOtest.exe
First\nSecond
First
Second
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I have now written an answer to explain that, though coproc's is already pretty good. Did you read it?

Comment: The compiler replaces \n (when inside string literals) with the newline character. The function getline does not perform such a replacement; you have to do the replacement yourself (see my answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C/C++ string literals ("...") the backslash is used to mark so called "escape sequences" for special characters. The *compiler* *translates* (replaces) the two characters '\' (ASCII code 92) followed by 'n' (ASCII code 110) by the new-line character (ASCII code 10). In a text file one would normally just hit the [RETURN] key to insert a newline character. If you really need to process input containing the two characters '\' and 'n' and want to handle them like a C/C++ compiler then you must explicitely replace them by the newline character:

```
replace(line, "\\n", "\n");
```

where you have to supply a replace function like this:
[Replace part of a string with another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418231/replace-part-of-a-string-with-another-string) (Standard C++ does not supply such a replace function by itself.)

Other escape sequences supported by C/C++ and similar compilers:

- \t -> [TAB]
- \" -> " (to distinguish from a plain ", which marks the end of a string literal, but is not part of the string itself!)
- \\ -> \ (to allow having a backslash in a string literal; a single backslash starts an escape sequence)

Comment: Aaaahhh it took me a while but I finally understood it! Sorry I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed.

Comment: I implemented the replace function as you suggested and it now works like a treat. Today I learned something new, thanks!

Comment: Is the third bullet to have two backslashes, such as \\ ?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yes - so also StackExchange uses some of these escape sequences! - corrected now

Answer (score 2):

The character indicated in a string literal by the escape sequence `\n` is not the same as the sequence of characters that looks like `\n`!

When you think you're assigning `First\nSecond`, you're not. In your source code, `\n` in a string literal is a "shortcut" for the invisible newline character. The string does not contain `\n` - it contains the newline character. It's automatically converted for you.

Whereas what you're reading from your file is the actual characters `\` and `n`.