# C++ escape control characters

Tags: c++, string, c++11, escaping

Is there a C++ function to escape the control characters in a string? For example, if the input is `"First\r\nSecond"` the output should be `"First\\0x0D\\0x0ASecond"`.

Comment: A greedy way of preforming this could be manually checking and replacing substrings within the main string. Refer to [C++ Replace part of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418231/replace-part-of-a-string-with-another-string)

Comment: There are various versions of HTTP code that performs what is known as "percent encoding", however it will encode any character that is not allowed to be in a URL.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard about any but it should be relatively easy to implement one:

```
unordered_map<char, string> replacementmap;
void initreplecementmap() {
    replacementmap['\''] = "\\0x27";
    replacementmap['\"'] = "\\0x22";
    replacementmap['\?'] = "\\0x3f";
    replacementmap['\\'] = "\\\\";
    replacementmap['\a'] = "\\0x07";
    replacementmap['\b'] = "\\0x08";
    replacementmap['\f'] = "\\0x0c";
    replacementmap['\n'] = "\\0x0a";
    replacementmap['\r'] = "\\0x0d";
    replacementmap['\t'] = "\\0x09";
    replacementmap['\v'] = "\\0x0b";
}

string replace_escape(string s) {
    stringstream ss;

    for (auto c: s) {
        if (replacementmap.find(c) != replacementmap.end()) {
            ss << replacementmap[c];
        } else {
            ss << c;
        }
    }
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: I would make the `replacementmap` variable into a static variable that is initialized with a list.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a C++ function to escape the control characters in a string?

By that, if you mean "Is there a standard library function that you can use to accomplish that?", the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of using raw ANSI escape codes as codes in C or C++, but i do know that some like

```
/n
```

work for creating newlines, so perhaps use

```
#define ActualEscapeCode AsciiEscapeCode
```

to substitute?