# How to use Regular Expressions to remove all instances of a specific phrase in an std::wstring?

Tags: c++, regex, string, replace, std

I am trying to follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32435076/5484426, but for std::wstring. So far, I have this:

```
std::wstring str = L"hello hi hello hi hello hi";
std::wregex remove = L"hi";
```

Now I want to do this: `regex_replace(str,remove,"");`
It doesn't look like regex_replace works for wstring though. How do I remove all instances of this string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::regex_replace` certainly works for `std::wstring`, and all other specializations of `std::basic_string`. However, the replacement format string's character type must match the character type of the regex and input string. This means you need a wide replacement format string:

```
std::regex_replace(str, remove, L"");
```

Apart from that, the constructor of `std::wregex` taking a `const wchar_t*` is explicit, so your copy-initialization will not work. Also, this overload of `std::regex_replace` returns a new string with the replacements done rather than doing them in place, which is something to be aware of.

Here is an [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8e37de24e7a5fbf) with these points considered:

```
std::wstring str = L"hello hi hello hi hello hi";
std::wregex remove{L"hi"};   

str = std::regex_replace(str, remove, L"");
```