# remove_copy usage with strings

Tags: c++, c++11, stl-algorithm

My string is `!!(!())`. I want to remove double exclamation from the string.

This works but it removes all exclamations

```
remove_copy(str.begin(), str.end(),ostream_iterator<char>(cout), '!');//gives (())
```

This does not work

```
remove_copy(str.begin(), str.end(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout), "!!");
```

Using the above line throws this error

/usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h:194:17: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
  { return *__it == _M_value; }

Comment: A reference makes it apparent that there's no overload taking a string specifically.

Comment: @chris ostream_iterator has `template <class T, class charT=char, class traits=char_traits<charT> >`. This means I can use string right?

Comment: @SamidhT string is a list of characters . remove_copy iterates through the   list and removes the char. It can work with list of strings as well.

Comment: @SamidhT, I meant `remove_copy`, not `ostream_iterator`. It doesn't take the same type as what you're iterating over.

Comment: I think you're asking about how to remove a substring from a `std::string`, so refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435003/how-to-remove-all-substrings-from-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the docs of remove_copy

```
OutputIterator remove_copy (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                          OutputIterator result, const T& val);

The function uses operator== to compare the individual elements to val.
```

So it uses every character of string and compares it with val. So second case would not work.

I ended up doing it this way

```
str.erase(str.find("!!"),2);
```

Also make sure that the string has "!!" otherwise program crashes

```
if(str.find("!!") != string::npos)
    str.erase(str.find("!!"),2);
```

Comment: Your edited code does the `find` twice, that's a waste of time, you've already found it once! It should be: `auto pos = str.find("!!"); if (pos != string::npos) str.erase(pos, 2);` Also, what if there is more than one occurrence of `"!!"` in the string? What if there is `"!!!"`? This is not a very general solution to the problem.

Comment: @JonathanWakely if there is "!!!" it really depends on how you want to handle it (2 instances of !! vs 1). Nevertheless I still agree with you, it's not generalized nor efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Why you cannot use `remove_copy(str.begin(), str.end(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout), "!!");` :

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_copy_if/

> pred
> Unary function that **accepts an element** in the range as argument, and returns a value convertible to bool. The value returned indicates
> whether the element is to be removed from the copy (if true, it is not
> copied).
> The function shall not modify its argument.
> This can either be a function pointer or a function object.