# Try to do the character delete for an array

Tags: c++

My question is that if I want to run a C++ program, which needs to input two things:

1. string `A`,
2. string `B`,

the Program's purpose is to remove all occurrences of `B` from `A`.

**Ex**: `A = adferttyu`, `B = adf`

Output: `erttyu`.

Comment: Could you share what you've tried?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question

Comment: What is your question ? What you give us is question that someone asked _you_. So what have you already tried to answer it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all substrings from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435003/how-to-remove-all-substrings-from-a-string)

Comment: I think you don't want to run a C++ program (If I got your question correctly).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Perhaps there's an implementation of sed in C++.  That would certainly achieve your aims if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This removes all substrings from a string**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void removeSubstrs(string& s, string& p) { 
  string::size_type n = p.length();
  for (string::size_type i = s.find(p);
      i != string::npos;
      i = s.find(p))
      s.erase(i, n);
}

int main() {

  string A = "adferttyu";
  string B = "adf";

  removeSubstrs(A, B);
  cout << A << endl;
}
```

**Output**: `erttyu`