# How to delete plain "\n" from a string in C++?

Tags: c++, std

As above, I'm trying to delete two character sub-string (not new-line character, just plain text) from a line.

What I am doing right now is `line.replace(line.find("\\n"), 3, "");` because I wanted to escape it, but I receive debug error saying that abort() has been called. Moreover, I am not sure about size 3, because first slash shouldn't be treated as a literal character.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. I am sure you have a typo on line 23, but still you better show us the code

Comment: You want to remove two characters ('\' and 'n'), not three. You also need to check that the string was found.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435003/how-to-remove-all-substrings-from-a-string

Comment: Have you tried raw string literal? Maybe those don't escape? R"(\\n)"

Comment: I rather would  use `std::regex_replace(line, "(\\n)+", "");` And your code doesn't account for case that you won't find the match. Or fact that you remove 3 characters instead of two.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Why would someone use regex to delete constant?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Now you have `\\n` problems.

Comment: @Zergeres Pros: clean one-liner, replaces all occurrences, got option to construct new string or write to existing one (if iterator syntax used), if required pattern changes to something else and can overlap, it would still work. Cons: performance, just what you said, to replace only one occurrence needs some magic.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit got me there.. that's what happens when I post from phone. Four backslashes, of course, regex needs its escaping too. Also you don't want to know what SwiftKey tried to suggest instead of code.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I was [joking](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But it was appropriate. Regex uses \ in samilar way to C\C++.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Actually that's a good point and I hadn't even thought about that. Hah!

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Do I get to hear SwiftKey's suggestion now, as a reward? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess [this](https://thispointer.com/how-to-remove-substrings-from-a-string-in-c/) is exactly what you're looking for:

```
std::string str = "This is \\n a string \\n containing \\n a lot of \\n stuff.";
const std::string to_erase = "\\n";

// Search for the substring in string
std::size_t pos = str.find(to_erase);
while (pos != std::string::npos) {
    // If found then erase it from string
    str.erase(pos, to_erase.length());
    pos = str.find(to_erase);
}
```

Note that you're likely getting std::abort because you are passing `std::string::npos` or the length 3 (not 2) to `std::string::replace`.

Comment: You are of course correct, I was typing in a haste. The code is operating as expected now, here you can see it in action: https://ideone.com/nHRc0k

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{

std::string head = "Hi //nEveryone. //nLets //nsee //nif //nthis //nworks";
std::string sub = "//n";
std::string::iterator itr;
for (itr = head.begin (); itr != head.end (); itr++)
{
  std::size_t found = head.find (sub);
  if (found != std::string::npos)
head.replace (found, sub.length (), "");

}
 std::cout << "after everything = " << head << std::endl;
}
```

i got the output as :

```
after everything = Hi Everyone. Lets see if this works
```

Comment: All is good, but why / instead of \ ? That's the berry of this question.