# Resolve std::replace compile errors

Tags: c++

I have the code line below

```
std::string inStr = "I go, I walk, I climb";
std::replace( inStr.begin(), inStr.end(), "I", "you");//C2782
```

With the above code lines, I am getting the compile error

```
error C2782: 'void std::replace(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,const _Ty &,const _Ty &)' : template parameter '_Ty' is ambiguous
```

What could be wrong with the in input parameters?

Comment: You can replace 1 char with 1 char.

Comment: Read and choose one of the examples in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418231/replace-part-of-a-string-with-another-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you, issue was because of size of `"I"` and `"You"` are different"

```
replace(inStr.begin(), inStr.end(), 'I', 'Y');
```

Try this,

```
size_t subStrinPos = -1;
do{
    subStrinPos = inStr.find('I', 0);
    if (subStrinPos != -1)
        inStr.replace(subStrinPos, strlen("I"), "You");
} while (subStrinPos != -1);
```

Comment: `"I"` and `"You"` aren't `const char`. If they were, there would be no problem.

Comment: `std::basic_string::find` does not return -1 it returns `std::basic_string::npos`.  Just because `npos` is equal to -1 you should state your intent.  Seeing `npos` will mean others who are looking at your code will instantly realise you are deliberately looking for the not found identifier and not a weird typo on your behalf.

Answer (score 4):

I believe *the error* is because the type of `"I"` is `const char[2]` and the type of `"you"` is `const char[4]` and not the `char*` you may be expecting.

The array decays to the pointer when required, but the template type deduction doesn't do that automatically.

*Bear in mind as well*, that with [`std::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) you will want to **replace individual elements** in the original string, so only use `char`.

---

A simply alternative snippet of code to replace the `"I"` with `"you"` is;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string inStr = "I go, I walk, I climb";
    //std::replace( inStr.begin(), inStr.end(), "I", "you");

    auto at = inStr.find("I");
    while (at < inStr.size()) {
        inStr.replace(at, 1, "you");
        at = inStr.find("I");
    }
    cout << inStr << endl;
}
```

You can use the [MS online compiler here](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net) to verify the code.

Answer (score 1):

`std::replace` is used to replace the **single element** in the **container** with another **element**. For `std::replace` on `std::string`, you only can replace **one char** to **another char** in your string container.

Comment: This is correct as far as it goes, but algorithms are applied to **sequences**, which are more general than containers. Containers are one way of creating sequences, but not the only way.