# Find sequence of chars in string c++ and erase it

Tags: c++, regex

I need find all occurrences of sequence: \r\n(some hex number)\r\n and delete this sequences from my string. Hexadecimal number doesn't start with 0x or x. It's just 20bb for example.

These sequences are chunks in http 1.1 protocol. I can't find them with string.find, maybe some regex would help.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

From the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418231/replace-part-of-a-string-with-another-string) I made this:

```
 std::string string("\r\n20BB\r\n");
 string = std::regex_replace(string, 
          std::regex("\r\n[0-9A-Fa-f]+\r\n"), "");
```

It should work. The `[0-9A-Fa-f]+` captures one or more hex digits.