# std::string replace not retaining the end?

Tags: c++, string

I want to replace a string within a string with `*`, using this code to replace everything between `he` and `ld` in `helloworld`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{  
       const std::string msg = "helloworld"; 

       const std::string from = "he";  

       const std::string to = "ld";  

       std::string s = msg;

       std::size_t startpos = s.find(from); 
       std::size_t endpos = s.find(to);  

       unsigned int l = endpos-startpos-2;  

       s.replace(startpos+2, endpos, l, '*');   

       std::cout << s;  
}
```

The output I got is `He*****`, but I wanted and expected `He*****ld`.
What did I get wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please provide what you have tried!!

Comment: maybe this may help you it seems similar to your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418231/replace-part-of-a-string-with-another-string

Comment: The first parameters to `replace` is start and length of the replaced part, not start and end. `s.replace(startpos+2,l,l,'*'); ` seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing all the characters after index two. Count the indexes and replace only the range you want.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  //this one for replace
  string str="Hello World";

  // replace string added to this one
  string str2=str;
  // You can use string position.
  str2.replace(2,6,"******");

  cout << str2 << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

- First parameter for starting character
- Second parameter for ending character
- And Third parameter for string

There is a several ways you can do this. This is a one simple method.

**UPDATE(After added your code):**

Change:

```
unsigned int l=endpos-startpos-2;  
s.replace(startpos+2,endpos,l,'*');
```

To:

```
unsigned int l=endpos-3;
s.replace(startpos+2,l,l,'*');
```

Because your `endpos` store position of character `d`. You need to substract `3` by `endpos` then `l` variable value become `7`. After that in `replace()` change second parameter to `l`.

read more about [replace()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/).

Comment: Don't answer _off-topic_ questions please. You are actively hurting the sites quality doing so.

Comment: I added this answer before off-topic. So only edited the answer to match the question before getting deleted

Comment: The question was _off-topic_ before it was finally marked so, what are you trying to tell me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.