# Replace all occurrences of one string with another in a stream of text

Tags: c++, string, replace

As the title says, how do I replace a string with another string? For example: the user would enter three inputs. The first input is the string that the program would replace; the second is the string that would replace input1; and the third is the string that would be printed out. So if:

Input1 = peanut

Input2 = coconut

Input3 = replace**peanut**replace

Output: replace**coconut**replace

I have started it but my program can only replace words with the same length. I tried searching my problem, but I do not understand the given solutions since I am just new at C/C++.

```
char replacing[100];
char replacement[100];
char original[1000];
int count;

cin >> replacing;
cin >> replacement;

while(! cin.eof())
{
    cin >> original;

    char * pch;


    pch = strstr (original, replacing);

    count = strlen(replacement);
    strncpy (pch, replacement, count);


    cout << original << endl;

}
```

Comment: If you want to learn C++, please go and learn C++. Your problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418231/replace-part-of-a-string-with-another-string). If you want to learn C, then please learn C only and look up what `strncpy` does. Don't mix it. That way you well end up doing it wrong *both* ways.

Comment: Try using `std::string`.   It has member function to find a substring and replace parts of it.   And it is easy to read from an input stream.

Comment: You may also be interested in [Why is `iostream::eof` inside a loop condition considered wrong?](/q/5605125)

Comment: We haven't covered `std::string` yet in class, so I don't really know how to use them. I will try to look into it though. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What about:

- You first find (if any) an occurrence of that string
- Use replace to substitute the occurrence with the second string

Here is something that should work:

```
    bool replaceFirst(string& input, const std::string& toBeReplaced, const std::string& replacement) {
    size_t start_pos = input.find(toBeReplaced);
    if(start_pos == std::string::npos)
        return false; //substring not found! 

    input.replace(start_pos, toBeReplaced.length(), replacement); //found. now i can replace!
    return true;
}
```

Since you are using an array of char instead of `string` you have to make sure that replacing does not lead you out of bound (strings auto-resize for you).

Comment: `from` doesn't seem to be defined in your code sample.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius fixed.

Comment: The problem is still present: `str.find(from);`.

Answer (score 0):

The key problem is that strncpy does not allocate (or free) any memory. This means that if `replacement` is shorter that `replacing`, part of `replacing` will not be overwritten. Similarly if `replacement` is longer it will overwrite beyond the end of `replacing`.

As already said, you would be better off using [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) (or some other C++ string class like Qt's [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) if Qt is your cup of tea).

One other little thing, in general with streams it's best not to just check for `eof`, rather write something like

```
while (cin >> original) {
```

This will terminate if the stream is in any fail state, not just `eof`.