# How to write to a file with string::replace method?

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line,wantedString,newString;
    fstream subor("test.txt");
    while (!subor.fail())  // read line from test.txt
    {
        getline(subor,line);
        line.substr(line.find("?")+1);
        wantedString=line.substr(line.find("?")+1); // will take everything after '?' character till 
'\n'
    }
    cout<<"Enter new text to replace wantedString :";
    getline(cin,newString);

    // how to use string::replace() please ?
    /I tried this but does not work
    getline(subor,line);
    line.replace(wantedString,string::npos,newString); 
    return 0;
}
```

In test.txt is written only one line :

```
something?replace
```

note: there is no '\n' in the file
 error thrown by compiler is :

```
    error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::replace(std::__cxx11::string&, const size_type&, std::__cxx11::string&)'
```

can you please answer working code with commented explaining why is it like you did it ?

I have studied string::replace() method here: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/

Is my logic of using string::find() as a starting point for string to be replaced ?

Comment: what overload of `string::replace`  did you want to call? There is none for the parameters you pass...

Answer (score 1):

> Is my logic of using string::find() as a starting point for string to be replaced ?

Yes, but then you threw away the iterator/index result of `find` and went to get the *substring* instead.

Replace doesn't take a string.

It takes an iterator/index.

So just pass what you got from `find`, into `replace`. (Be careful of edge cases! Check for errors! Read the documentation for both functions.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream subor("test.txt");

    string line;
    while (getline(subor,line))
    {
        // Find the index of the character after the first '?'
        const size_t wantedStringPos = line.find("?")+1;

        // Prompt for a replacement string
        cout << "Enter new text to replace wantedString: ";
        string newString;
        getline(cin,newString);

        // Perform the replacement
        line.replace(wantedStringPos, string::npos, newString);

        // Now do something with `line`
        // [TODO]
    }
}
```

*(I've also fixed [an off-by-one error in your loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/560648).)*

You then need to actually write the new, modified string back to the file: the file doesn't automatically get updated in sync with the copy of the data you previously read out from it.

Comment: so i CHANGED 'string wantedString' to 'int wantedString = line.find("?")+1', ADDED 'string replace = line.replace(wantedString,string::npos,newString)'  AND tried to update file WITH 'subor<<replace;' but this changes nothing ... why ?   and sorry, i cant format it to be more readable ... hope you understand

Comment: @IvoJOKERDurec You're still passing a string to `replace`. You should read the documentation to find out how to use `replace`. And for formatting assistance click the "help" link next to the comment box; it'll teach you how to make it readable.

Comment: i do not understand ... what should i pass there ? on the link i posted is written that the third argument is string, or am i missing something ?

Comment: @IvoJOKERDurec And what about the first argument?

Comment: the first argument is "Another string object, whose value is copied."  from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/ and i tried to change string to size_t of wantedString, but this does not work either ...

Comment: @IvoJOKERDurec That is not the first argument, for any of the overloads. The "Arguments" section of that page is not in the order you give the arguments. Look at the declarations at the top of the page for the available combinations. Then look up the _name_ of each argument in the "Arguments" section for more information on how to provide it.

Comment: can you please just tell me what am i missing ? i tried to figure it out by your hints but still no result ... i also found and tried this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418231/replace-part-of-a-string-with-another-string  but this worked only when i run it in program ... without file included. when i tried to getline from file and find "?", it did not replaced within the file even if it compiled ... isn't problem in saving edited file somehow ? Maybe it works, but it will not save changes to the file. What do you think ?

Comment: @IvoJOKERDurec I've added a sketch. There are a few logical errors with your original code

Comment: so in while loop you have made const ... i tought i cant make a const while program is running and when i cout<<line it writes exactly what it should, but still when i want to write it in file like subor<<line; it will not change.And I want to thank you for your patience with me :)

Comment: @IvoJOKERDurec I made `wantedStringPos` `const`, because it doesn't need to _not_ be `const`. I didn't have to do that, but it's a good habit for anything that doesn't need to change after initialisation.

Comment: @IvoJOKERDurec _"still when i want to write it in file like subor<<line; it will not change"_ Yeah you have a separate issue here really - trying to read from the file _and write to it at the same time_ is more complicated. I can't decide yet whether to expand this answer to include that, or just get you to ask a new question (actually it's been asked before so you should search) but either way I will come back later